# KEDA can't connect with RABBITMQ service

Tags: kubernetes, rabbitmq, autoscaling, keda

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: spring-consumer-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: spring-consumer
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: spring-consumer
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: spring-consumer
          image: secnalouti/sigrepo:tagname
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8000
```

```
apiVersion: keda.sh/v1alpha1
kind: ScaledObject
metadata:
  name: spring-consumer
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    name: spring-consumer-deployment
  triggers:
    - type: rabbitmq
      metadata:
        queueName: projqueue
        host: amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672
        port: "5672"
        username: guest
        password: guest
        queueLength: "5"
  minReplicaCount: 1
  maxReplicaCount: 5
  pollingInterval: 10
  cooldownPeriod: 40
  advanced:
    horizontalPodAutoscalerConfig:
      behavior:
        scaleDown:
          stabilizationWindowSeconds: 300
          policies:
            - type: Pods
              value: 1
              periodSeconds: 60
        scaleUp:
          stabilizationWindowSeconds: 300
          policies:
            - type: Pods
              value: 2
              periodSeconds: 60
```

```
 Warning  KEDAScalerFailed         0s (x4 over 3s)  keda-operator  error establishing rabbitmq connection: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5672: connect: connection refused
  Warning  ScaledObjectCheckFailed  0s (x4 over 3s)  keda-operator  Failed to ensure HPA is correctly created for ScaledObject
```

Hi im new to k8s and keda so sorry if I misspresented the probleme ,
I'm trying  to make my spring app consumer(the spring app work and i can get the legnth of the queue with get API ) scale based on queue length after I applyed the deployment file it runnig fine but the autoscaling file retunr that warning  KEDAScalerFailed and ScaledObjectCheckFailed when i execute kubectl describe scaledobject (I can access to rabbitmq UI via http://localhost:15672/) and this is what k

```
rabbitmq-86b799f574-btn9p                                         1/1     Running   2 (5h28m ago)   20d
```

and this is what k get scaledobject return

```
spring-consumer         apps/v1.Deployment   spring-consumer-deployment   1     5     rabbitmq                                     False   Unknown   Unknown    143m
```

thanks for any kind of help

Comment: You configured `amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672` but it can't be localhost. Use the rabbitmq service fqdn

Comment: can please give more details ?

Comment: I changed the host to         host: amqp://guest:guest@rabbitmq.default.svc.cluster.local and it worked thanks